# Joint Density Function (Find C1)

Tags: calculus, functions, density-function

How exactly can I find the value of $C_{1}$ so that f is a joint density function?

$$f(r,\theta)=
\begin{cases}
C_{1}(1-r^{2}), & \text{if} (r,\theta)∈ R\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

R is the region inside of r = 2+4cosθ (which includes the little loop)

Comment: Enforce the total probability $\iint_R f(r,\theta)\,\mathrm{d}A(r,\theta)=1$.

Comment: For $|r^2\gt 1$, the density is negative - not allowed!

Comment: R is the region inside of r = 2+4cosθ (which includes the big and little loop)